# Unable to get the locale encoding in Ubuntu 14.04, Apache/2.4.7, libapache2-mod-wsgi-py3, Python 3.4 virtualenv, Django 1.86

Tags: django, apache, python-3.x, ubuntu

I am trying to setup a simple Django app using this tutorial:
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-serve-django-applications-with-apache-and-mod_wsgi-on-ubuntu-14-04

My configuration is:
Ubuntu 14.04, Apache/2.4.7, libapache2-mod-wsgi-py3, Python 3.4, Django 1.86

I keep getting the following error in the apache log whenever I try to access the server using its IP:

```
ImportError: No module named 'encodings'
Fatal Python error: Py_Initialize: Unable to get the locale encoding
ImportError: No module named 'encodings'
[Sat Nov 07 01:26:56.505373 2015] [core:notice] [pid 20920:tid 140075144152960] AH00051: child pid 21716 exit signal Aborted (6), possible coredump in /etc/apache2
[Sat Nov 07 01:26:56.505478 2015] [core:notice] [pid 20920:tid 140075144152960] AH00051: child pid 21717 exit signal Aborted (6), possible coredump in /etc/apache2
Fatal Python error: Py_Initialize: Unable to get the locale encoding
ImportError: No module named 'encodings'
```

My virtual hosts file looks as follows:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>  

    ServerAdmin 
    ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias www.example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/example.com/public_html

    Alias /static /home/admin/myproject/static
    <Directory /home/admin/myproject/static>
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    <Directory /home/admin/myproject/myproject>
        <Files wsgi.py>
            Require all granted
        </Files>
    </Directory>

    WSGIDaemonProcess myproject python-path=/home/admin/myproject:/home/admin/myproject/myprojectenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages
    WSGIProcessGroup myproject
    WSGIScriptAlias / /home/admin/myproject/myproject/wsgi.py    

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined    

</VirtualHost>
```

There were no errors while setting up Django in the virtualenv.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was finally able to solve this. As I am using Python 3.4, I needed to install libapache2-mod-wsgi-py3 earlier. This installs a precompiled version of mod-wsgi into the Apache modules folder at /usr/lib/apache2/modules.
It also installed the apache module for wsgi-express.

The modules to be loaded by Apache are controlled by configuration files in  /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/

Here there are 2 files for each module. A .load and a .conf file. I saw the files wsgi.load & wsgi.conf and also wsgi-express.load & wsgi-express.conf
The .load files mention the .so module to be loaded

Both the .load files had a line beginning with:

```
LoadModule wsgi_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/...
```

That means the wsgi_module was being loaded twice. I used to receive a warning whenever I would restart Apache 2, that mod-wsgi is already loaded so skipping. So the first thing I did was disabled mod-wsgi_express

```
a2dismod wsgi_express
```

That left only 1 mod-wsgi to be loaded. This should work.

I actually went a step further and compiled the latest mod-wsgi from source following https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/installing-mod_wsgi-on-ubuntu-12-04

The latest mod-wsgi can be found here https://github.com/GrahamDumpleton/mod_wsgi/releases

That compilation went smoothly and I got a module named mod_wsgi.so-3.4 in /usr/lib/apache2/modules

In my /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/wsgi.load I put in :

```
LoadModule wsgi_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_wsgi.so-3.4
```

After restarting Apache it worked!